# What is the standard form of the equation of a circle with its center at (2, -3) and passing through the point (-2, 0)?

Tags: geometry

I need help solving this problem. I've tried everything and I just cant get it right for nothing. Can someone please solve this for me

Comment: The standard form is $(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=c^2$, where $(a, b)$ is the center and $c$ is the radius. Can you find these quantities?

Comment: Can you solve it

Comment: Another one would be $ x = \pm \sin \left( \cos^{-1} y \right) $ but I guess it's not a standard one. **EDIT**: By $ \cos^{-1} $ I mean $ \arccos $.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A=(-2,0)$, and  $B=(x,y) $ be another point on the circle, then we have  $$ || AC || =||BC ||= r$$ where  $C=(2,-3)$ the center of the radius, and  $ ||.||$ refers to the distance between two  points. Now develope the above formula to end up with an equation containing $x$ and  $y$. This is the  equation of your circle.

Answer (score 0):

You can find radius by distance formula is √2-(-2)^2+ (-3+0)^2= 5and then use equation (x-2)^2+(y+3)^2=25 and on solving we get x^2+y^2-4x+6y-12=0

Comment: We don't know if the coordinate system is a Cartesian coordinate system :-)